# How to re-direct to another view controller if user's Facebook session is valid?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to check to see if a user's Facebook session is valid and if it is then redirect them to a certain view controller.

```
 if ([facebook isSessionValid]) {
   NSLog(@"session is valid");

 }
```

I also tried:

if ([facebook isSessionValid]) {

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SessionIsValid" sender:self];
```

}

and dragged a Storyboard segue with the identifier "SessionIsValid" to the viewController I want to be re-directed to if `Facebook isSessionValid`

I was wondering how I'd go about doing this. I'm using a Storyboard in an ARC enabled app.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard create a segue from your current viewcontroller to wherever you want the user to go if the session is valid. Then, in your code above add something like:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SessionIsValid" sender:self];`

You set the identifier by clicking on the segue that was created in the storyboard.

Comment: thanks. I just tried that but it simply logs the user in and remains on the first view controller.

Comment: How are you triggering the segue? If you are ctrl-dragging from a button, for example, you would need to change "sender". Otherwise, you can drag from the "viewcontroller" in which case "self" is appropriate.  Why don't you add a screen shot of your storyboard and a bit more of your code.

Comment: I'm dragging from the view controller and not a button. I was the view to see if the session is valid on a viewWillAppear and then act conditionally after that. It seems like the problem is with the session not detecting if it's valid and not with the segue.